# How To write a function to Check for a Sequence of integers in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, function

I'm trying to figure out why the code I wrote to find a sequence of integers in any given array is not catching all the instances. Could you help, please?

Here's the code:

```
def array123(nums):
  if len(nums) < 3:
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
      if nums[i:i + 3] == [1, 2, 3]:
        return True
      return False
```

Comment: can you also give an example input and desired output ?

Comment: Example input: [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 2 3, 4]

Desired output: True

Example input: [3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]

Desired output: False

Answer (score 1):

The `return False` part should be indented as follows.

```
def array123(nums):
  if len(nums) < 3:
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
      if nums[i:i + 3] == [1, 2, 3]:
        return True
    return False    # This should be indented this way.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def array123(nums):
nums_to_string = str(nums)
if len(nums_to_string) < 3:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(len(nums_to_string) - 1):
        if nums_to_string[i:i + 3] == "123":
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: And please make sure any code posted here is accurate. This has an obvious `IndentationError`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def array123(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i:i + 3] == [1, 2, 3]:
            return True
    return False

 """'i' in range and then go for the length of nums because I don't know how long nums are going to be as a list. I will say -2 because I don't want to go all the way to the end. so -2 back because I'm going to be counting in steps of three."""
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some explanation in addition to just the code.